# Generating Function question for selecting r unordered blocks.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

A box of alphabet blocks contains $6$ of each $A,B,C,D$, $2$ of each of $E,F,G$, $4$ of each of $H,I,J,K,L,M$, and one of each other letter. Find the generating function for selecting $r$ (unordered) blocks from this set.

So I have,

$(1+x+x^2 +x^3 +x^4 )^6 (1+x+x^2 +x^3 )^2 (1+x+x^2 +...+x^6 )^4 (x+x^2 +...+x^{13} )$

Not sure if I did this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've lost a $1$ from the last bracket.

I think what you have there is the generating function for the problem
when you have 4 each of A, B, C, D, E, F, 3 each of G and H, 6 each of
I, J, K and L, and 13 Ms.

Comment: Another answer i have is $(1+x+x^2+...+x^6)^4(1+x+x^2)^3(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^6 ...$   And I am unsure about the last part for one of each other letter. Is  the same $(1+x+x^2+...+x^{13})$?

Comment: You would get a factor $(1+x+\cdots+x^{13})$ whenever there's a letter you have 13 copies of.

Comment: O i see now thanks.